# Confusion in a multivariable cubic polynomial.

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

**WARNING**:-

This question may have wrong tags.

**HISTORY**:-

After watching an old numberphile video(https://youtu.be/wymmCdLdPvM)(this video has nothing to do with my question) ,I got interested in the equation: $x^3+y^3+z^3=k$

Now being a high school student ,it is not likely that I am gonna prove some hundred years old uncracked problem surrounding the equation.

But you know, we all have false hopes, and so I started playing around with the beautiful equation.

After writing down the equation in a page, I remembered "*Oo, I have to be smart to solve problems... ooooo.*" But I still kept playing with the equation and decided to write the sum of three cubes as a sum of 2 cubes

Here's what I did:

Assume that $x\neq -y$

$x^3+y^3+z^3=k$

$\implies x^3+y^3=k-z^3$
**-eq(1)**

$\implies (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=k-z^3$

$\implies x^2-xy+y^2=\frac{k-z^3}{x+y}$

$\implies (x+y)^2=\frac{k-z^3}{x+y}+3xy$

$\implies (x+y)^3=k-z^3+3xy(x+y)$

$\implies (x+y)^3+z^3=k-3x^2y-3xy^2$

$\implies (x+y)^3+z^3-x^3-y^3=k-(x+y)^3$

$\implies 2(x+y)^3+z^3=k+x^3+y^3$

Combining this with **eq(1)** will give:

$2(x+y)^3+z^3=k+k-z^3$

$\implies (x+y)^3+z^3=k$

**Confusion and my question**:-

I just found that $x^3+y^3+z^3=k=(x+y)^3+z^3$

$\implies x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y)^3+z^3$

What does that supposed to mean? I gave absolutely no restrictions to $x,y,z$ except the assumption in my first step, but that assumption shouldn't really matter.

The equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=(x+y)^3+z^3$

$\implies$ that either $x$ or $y$ is $0$.

Which means that I cannot add three cubes. What does that supposed to mean?!!

Please tell me what I did wrong in the steps.

Comment: Why do you include a link to a video if it has nothing to do with your question?

Comment: @David Scholz, Just for the context..... just to tell that where does the story starts from. And I gave the link because even if I say that the video has nothing to do with my question, people would still want to see the video because they are humans and humans have curiosity.

Comment: It is very likely that you did a mistake, namely assuming somewhere $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3$, which is not true in general.

Comment: You have a sign error. You should have $k+3x^2 y + 3x y^2$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, that is my point. I cannot find where I did that assumption.

Comment: @Cameron Williams, holy sh*t. That is a really bad mistake. Does that removes the paradox?

Comment: Yep it will. You'll see that you basically just did a bunch of variable shuffling and it didn't really mean anything after you fix that. That's not a bad thing. You're exploring mathematics and accepting of errors (as well as knowing that you probably goofed) and that's what matters. Most of us did stuff like this at some point perhaps out of naivete but over time we have learned to be better mathematicians. You don't get better by only having successes. Failures and mistakes are just as important.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to prove

Comment: @Cameron Williams, yeah that does resolve the paradox. $(x+y)^3+z^3=k+3x^2y+3xy^2$$\implies (x+y)^3+z^3+x^3+y^3=k+(x+y)^3$$\implies x^3+y^3+z^3=k$.

Comment: @Cameron Williams, you can post my mistake as an answer because that is what the question asks for? (By the way thanks for the great words)

Comment: Someone else got it already :)

Comment: @Cameron Williams, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made some sign errors.

From the line
$$(x+y)^3=k-z^3+3xy(x+y)$$
the next line should be
$$
(x+y)^3+z^3=k+3x^2y+3xy^2
$$
Even allowing that error, from the line
$$
(x+y)^3+z^3=k-3x^2y-3xy^2
$$
the next line should be
$$
(x+y)^3+z^3+x^3+y^3=k-(x+y)^3
$$
An easy way to have found the error on your own is to choose $x,y,z,k$ such that
$$
x^3+y^3+z^3=k
$$
e.g., $x=1,y=2,z=3,k=36$, and then substitute line-by-line until equality fails on some line.